# In IF_NET mode POST_ROUTING hook does not get called

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, network-programming, netfilter, bridge

I have written a netfilter module to check packets incoming and outgoing from the Linux box for some specific patterns.

```
nfho1.owner             = THIS_MODULE;
nfho1.hook              = dhcp_hook_function;
nfho1.hooknum           = NF_INET_POST_ROUTING;
nfho1.priority          = NF_IP_PRI_FIRST;

if(use_bridge == 1)
{
        nfho1.pf            = PF_BRIDGE; // on bridge interface
}
else
{
        nfho1.pf            = PF_INET; // not on bridge interface
}


nfho2.owner      = THIS_MODULE;
nfho2.hook       = data_hook_function;
nfho2.hooknum    = NF_INET_PRE_ROUTING;
nfho2.priority   = NF_IP_PRI_FIRST;

if(use_bridge == 1)
{
        nfho2.pf         = PF_BRIDGE; // on bridge interface
}
else
{
        nfho2.pf         = PF_INET;
}

nf_register_hook(&nfho1);
nf_register_hook(&nfho2);
```

The use_bridge parameter decides which Protocol Family to use.

However, My question is, **IS THE PF_BRIDGE necessary.**

**Test Cases:**
Case 1: br0 is configured using brctl

with PF_BRIDGE the post_routing hooks get called.
without PF_BRIDGE the post_routing hook does not get called.

Why doesn't the post-routing hook get called. AFAIK the post routing hook cannot be bypassed.

Case 2: br0 is not confugured but ip_forwarding is ON.

without PF_BRIDGE both hooks get called.
I do not configure PF_BRIDGE for this test case.

So why is PF_BRIDGE required to make the POST ROUTING hook to be called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out why this is happening so sharing:

By default in Linux the iptables will deal with a IP layer packet while ebtables deal with Layer 2 packets.

```
However there is a configuration parameter to be set in:
/proc/sys/net/bridge/bridge-nf-call-iptables.
```

**If it is **set to 1 then even the bridge layer packets seem to be calling the iptables hooks.**

I checked this in my set up and turned it on!!

Answer (score 0):

Are you modifying the packet at all? There are a few cases in which br_nf_post_routing doesn't pass the POST_ROUTING hook back up to the IP stack. It looks like one such case is when the IP netfilter hooks have done something with it (http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/net/bridge/br_netfilter_hooks.c#L808)

Hope this helps. I'm currently trying to understand the Netfilter linkages myself. Good luck!

Comment: Dear Joel C,

I figured out the answer with some digging into the PF_BRIDGE on the net.

There is a parameter /proc/sys/net/bridge/nf_bridge_call_iptables.